# PDO - Update DB - Similar Pattern - One Working Another Not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I basically new in PDO and just use it since about 3 days ago. Struggling really hard to get my stuff working with it. Have looking around here, but it just make me more confused, since I couldn't find matched question.

I have two update mysql DB functionality developed with PDO. One working and another not. Can't figure out where the problem really is, since everything looks fine. These are the codes:

**NOT WORKING**

```
// NOT WORKING    

$updv = "UPDATE affiliate_link SET cj_tracker_url=:cjtr, cj_aid=:midr, cj_pid=:fidr, cj_isc:cisr WHERE ID=:ID";

            $arrv = array(
            'ID' => 1,
            'cjtr' => $cju,
            'midr' => $aai,
            'fidr' => $pai,
            'cisr' => $gis
            );
            $exdv = $condb -> prepare($updv, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
            $exdv -> execute($arrv);
```

**WORKING**

```
//WORKING
        $updb = "UPDATE right_sidebar SET topright_sidebar=:trs, middleright_sidebar=:mrs, bottomright_sidebar=:brs WHERE ID=:ID";

        $arrb = array(
        "ID" => 1,
        "trs" => $trb,
        "mrs" => $mrb,
        "brs" => $brb
        );
        $exdb = $condb -> prepare($updb, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $exdb->execute($arrb);
```

Hope somebody would give me a clue. Here is the error message:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
```

Best Regards

Comment: I guess you have a typo in your query this `cj_isc:cisr` should be `cj_isc = :cisr`

Comment: NEITHER of the queries should work. the key/values you pass into should execute() call are missing the `:` in the placeholder names anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an "=" - your query in the not-working code should be:

```
$updv = "UPDATE affiliate_link SET cj_tracker_url=:cjtr, cj_aid=:midr, cj_pid=:fidr, cj_isc=:cisr WHERE ID=:ID";
```

Comment: OMG.. thank you very much.. I couldn't saw it before..

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your SQL

```
cj_isc:cisr
```

when it should be

```
cj_isc=:cisr
```

you are missing the = sign.